# oracle lookup translation for a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a table with data below

```
create table A 
(id number, 
code varchar2(100));

insert into A values 
(1, '20,21,22'); 
insert into A values 
(2, '22,23,24'); 

commit;
```

[image]

```
create table code_descriptions
(
code_id number, 
code_desc varchar2(100)); 

insert into code_descriptions values 
(20, 'ABC'); 
insert into code_descriptions values 
(21, 'BBC'); 
insert into code_descriptions values 
(22, 'CAP'); 
insert into code_descriptions values 
(23, 'INC'); 
insert into code_descriptions values 
(24, 'ABC'); 

commit;
```

[image]

I would like to come up with sql to update table A code values with descriptions

[image: 1,]

Could you please suggest any functions or ideas, to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you storing comma-separated values - rather than one row per value?

Comment: well, that's how we get the data from an application to the table. that is not in my control.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: thought of creating intermediate temp table to convert the column values into rows and then join to the description table to update back. I am looking to see if there is any better approach that that.

Answer (score 2):

You can tokenize your comma-separated lists:

```
select id, level as rn, regexp_substr(code, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as code_id
from a
connect by level <= regexp_count(code, ',') + 1
and id = prior id
and prior dbms_random.value is not null;

        ID         RN CODE_ID
---------- ---------- -------
         1          1 20     
         1          2 21     
         1          3 22     
         2          1 22     
         2          2 23     
         2          3 24
```

Then use that as a CTE (subquery factoring) and join to the descriptions (I've made it a left-join so you choose how to handle any missing codes):

```
with cte (id, rn, code_id) as (
  select id, level, regexp_substr(code, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from a
  connect by level <= regexp_count(code, ',') + 1
  and id = prior id
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
)
select cte.id, cte.rn, cte.code_id, coalesce(cd.code_desc, '??') as code_desc
from cte
left join code_descriptions cd on cd.code_id = cte.code_id;

        ID         RN CODE_ID CODE_DESC
---------- ---------- ------- ---------
         1          1 20      ABC      
         1          2 21      BBC      
         2          1 22      CAP      
         1          3 22      CAP      
         2          2 23      INC      
         2          3 24      ABC
```

and then aggregate those back into single comma-separated values:

```
with cte (id, rn, code_id) as (
  select id, level, regexp_substr(code, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from a
  connect by level <= regexp_count(code, ',') + 1
  and id = prior id
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
)
select cte.id,
  listagg(coalesce(cd.code_desc, '??'), ',') within group (order by rn) as code
from cte
left join code_descriptions cd on cd.code_id = cte.code_id
group by cte.id;

        ID CODE            
---------- ----------------
         1 ABC,BBC,CAP     
         2 CAP,INC,ABC
```

and then merge or us a correlated update:

```
update a
set code = (
  with cte (id, rn, code_id) as (
    select id, level, regexp_substr(code, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
    from a
    connect by level <= regexp_count(code, ',') + 1
    and id = prior id
   and prior dbms_random.value is not null
  ) 
  select listagg(coalesce(cd.code_desc, '??'), ',') within group (order by rn) as code
  from cte
  left join code_descriptions cd on cd.code_id = cte.code_id
  where cte.id = a.id
  group by cte.id
);

2 rows updated.

select * from a;

        ID CODE            
---------- ----------------
         1 ABC,BBC,CAP     
         2 CAP,INC,ABC
```

or

```
rollback; -- just to undo previous update

merge into a
using (
  with cte (id, rn, code_id) as (
    select id, level, regexp_substr(code, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
    from a
    connect by level <= regexp_count(code, ',') + 1
    and id = prior id
   and prior dbms_random.value is not null
  ) 
  select cte.id, listagg(coalesce(cd.code_desc, '??'), ',') within group (order by rn) as code
  from cte
  left join code_descriptions cd on cd.code_id = cte.code_id
  group by cte.id
) tmp
on (tmp.id = a.id)
when matched then update set a.code = tmp.code;

2 rows merged.

select * from a;

        ID CODE            
---------- ----------------
         1 ABC,BBC,CAP     
         2 CAP,INC,ABC
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=33e20ba36e4da4dcbe3c01690d3892f3)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is if the number of elements in the "code" column of table A is fixed - by directly gluing the subqueries to the code_descriptions table by codes (we cut each code from the enumeration line).

Comment: i did not understand. Could you please explain.

Comment: select id, 
           ( select code_desc from code_descriptions where code_id = substr(code,1,instr(code, ',',1,1)-1) ) ||','||
           ( select code_desc from code_descriptions where code_id = substr(code,instr(code, ',',1,1)+1,instr(code, ',',1,2)-instr(code, ',',1,1)-1)) ||','||
           ( select code_desc from code_descriptions where code_id =substr(code,instr(code, ',',1,2)+1))
from table_A